# Reading the Web Content Display portlet parameters

Tags: liferay, portlet

I display articles in a Web Content Display portlet (**Liferay**).

The question is :

How can I read that portlet URL parameters from another portlet?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't. Why would you want to read another portlet's URL parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSR-268 standard Inter Portlet Communication client or server side.

See liferay wiki: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Inter-portlet+communication
And for shared render parameters and event communication: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Eventing+and+Shared+Render+Parameters

Hope this helps, regards